# How to build a minimum-height binary search tree recursively?

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have an array of 26 integers, 1-26 in order a[0]=1...a[25]=26.  I have been playing with this code for a while, and I can't seem to determine why the current code I have isn't working properly.  This is my build method:

```
public static binaryNode buildBalanced(int[] a, int low, int high)
{
    if(low > high)
    {
        return null;
    }
double mid = Math.floor((low + high)/2);
int iMid = (int)mid;
binaryNode node = new binaryNode(a[(int)iMid]);
node.setLeftChild(buildBalanced(a, low, (int)(iMid-1)));
node.setRightChild(buildBalanced(a, (int)(iMid+1), high));
return node;
}
```

binaryNode is a node that has a right child, a left child, and info.

Now when I try to print out the three traversals (in-Order, pre-Order, and post-Order) this is what I get:

InOrder:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26

PreOrder:
13 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26

PostOrder:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 13

It seems to me that this code isn't working properly.  Or is it my in-,pre-, and post-order methods that are wrong?

These are the three print methods I am using:
InOrder:

```
public static void printInOrder(binaryNode current, Queue<binaryNode> queue)
{

    if(current == null)
    {
        queue.add(current);
        return;
    }
    if (current.getLeftChild() != null)
    {
        printInOrder(current.getLeftChild(), queue);
    }
    queue.add(current);
    if(current.getRightChild() != null)
    {
        printInOrder(current.getRightChild(), queue);
    }
    if(current.getParent() == null)
    {
        while(!queue.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.print(queue.remove().getInfo() + " ");               
        }
    }
}
```

PreOrder:

```
public static void printPreOrder(binaryNode current, Queue<binaryNode> queue)
{
     if(current == null)
        {
            queue.add(current);
            return;
        }
        queue.add(current);
        if (current.getLeftChild() != null)
        {
            printInOrder(current.getLeftChild(), queue);
        }
        if(current.getRightChild() != null)
        {
            printInOrder(current.getRightChild(), queue);
        }
        if(current.getParent() == null)
        {
            while(!queue.isEmpty())
            {
                System.out.print(queue.remove().getInfo() + " ");               
            }
        }
}
```

PostOrder:

```
public static void printPostOrder(binaryNode current, Queue<binaryNode> queue)
{
    if(current == null)
    {
        queue.add(current);
        return;
    }
    if (current.getLeftChild() != null)
    {
        printInOrder(current.getLeftChild(), queue);
    }
    if(current.getRightChild() != null)
    {
        printInOrder(current.getRightChild(), queue);
    }
    queue.add(current);
    if(current.getParent() == null)
    {
        while(!queue.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.print(queue.remove().getInfo() + " ");               
        }
    }

}
```

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your build step looks fine.  However your traversals are more complicated than they need to be.  You only need a queue if you want to do an iterative traversal instead of using recursion.

Since you are using recursion, the traversals require no queue:

```
public static void printInOrder(binaryNode current)
{

    if(current == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    printInOrder(current.getLeftChild());
    System.out.print(current.getInfo() + " ");
    printInOrder(current.getRightChild());
}
```

Comment: Also to answer your question as to why your pre and post order traversals don't look right, take a look at the recursive function you are calling on the child nodes.  Should it be printInOrder?

Comment: That helps so much, thank you!  And yes I see what you mean, I realized that incorrect call a few minutes ago.  Thank you, it's working perfectly now!